# What is the equivalent of the Russian "Masha-rasteryasha" (Masha who loses things)?

Tags: idiom-requests, translation, russian

Is there any equivalent for the Russian expression "Маша-растеряша" ("Masha-rasteryasha") in English? Its word-for-word translation is "Masha (a girl's name) who always loses things". The first and second parts of it rhyme with each other, and it's an informal, slightly teasing expression. Are there any equivalent English expressions modelled on the same structure: a person's name + a word rhyming with this name and describing a person loosing things (for example, something similar to Silly Billy or Plain Jane)?
You could give both variants both with female amd male names.

Comment: Pippi Longstocking and Amelia Bedelia were kind but scatterbrained characters in fiction.

Comment: There's no shortage of [fictional exemplars](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForgetfulJones), like the Muppet [Forgetful Jones](https://muppet.fandom.com/wiki/Forgetful_Jones) or Roger Hargreaves's [Little Miss Scatterbrain](https://mrmen.fandom.com/wiki/Little_Miss_Scatterbrain). I'm not sure that any of them have really become part of the English language. And none quite fit the specific pattern requested.

Comment: I suppose _Dolly Daydream_ is related, but uses alliteration rather than rhyme. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dolly_Daydream).

Comment: Russian, having the morphological resources to coin idiomatic nicknames, does so frequently. English doesn't any more, except for the odd family nickname.

Comment: about the best we have in English - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/would_lose_one%27s_head_if_it_wasn%27t_attached